# Degree and quasi projective family

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a quasi-projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n}\times\mathbb{P}^m$. If $p\in \mathbb{P}^m$, we define the degree of $V_p$ as the degree of its closure in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

**Question :** $\exists C>0,~~\forall p\in \mathbb{P}^m,~~\deg(V_p)\leq C$ ?

**Remark :** If $V$ is projective, it is true. (Using generic flatness and noetherian induction).

**Edit :** If $f:V\to \mathbb{P}^m$ is the second projection, $V_p$ is $f^{-1}(p)$ (with the natural scheme structure).

Comment: What is the definition of $V_p$ ?

Comment: Why can't you take the closure $\bar V$ of V in $\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m$ and apply your argument in the projective case? It seems to me that $\deg V_p\leq \deg (\bar V)_p$, so this should be OK.